# Issue retrieving value of People Picker using PnP PowerShell for SP 2013

Tags: people-picker, pnp-powershell

I'm retrieving all of the values from a list and it's working fine on all of the fields except the People and Group Picker column.

It returns:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
```

I'm trying to retrieve it using the following syntax (although I've tried everything):

```
 "Content Author" = $libitem["KBContentAuthor"].LookupValue
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also additional fetch details as below via `Get-PnPUser` command:

```
$value = $libitem["KBContentAuthor"]

$user = Get-PnPUser -Identity $value.LookupId

# added this just for explanation, you can remove it from the code
$email = $user.Email  
$username = $user.LoginName
$fullname = $user.Title

"Content Author" = $user.Title
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  I must say I spent many hours researching this.  Can you point me in the direction of the documentation that explained this?  Cheers!

Comment: No such official documentation, i found it from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1592)